# Changing primary color in material-ui causes material-ui datepicker to crash

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, materialdatepicker

I am using the `material-ui/pickers` library to add a `datepicker`.
but it throws the following exception.

"[image]

I investigated the issue and understood that, if I override the primary and secondary colour for the project, it throws the error. Otherwise, the picker works fine.

This is how I added custom primary and secondary colors.

```
palette: {
    primary: {
        main: '#1D2951',
        contrastText: 'white',
    },
    secondary: {
        main: '#28D9C3',
        contrastText: 'white',
    },
},
```

I tried with different versions of the datepicker but could not resolve the issue.

Library versions:

```
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.56",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
```

Comment: I think I can get the problem right, but did you try to put #fff instead of white?

Comment: Yes, I added `default : {background: '#fff' } ` in the palette snippet that I attached. Did not work.

Comment: so you mean the problem won't be fixed bt `contrastText: '#fff'`? If yes, could you add more information about where the error tirgered?

Comment: `contrastText: '#fff'` has zero effect here sadly. The error triggers when the calendar component is about to open(after clicking the calendar icon).

Comment: there may be two things useful for your resolving this issue you have faced. [1](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers/search?q=theme.palette) & 2 wrap a new default Theme provider around your material-ui/pickers datepicker

Comment: Your comments helped me to realize what I needed to do. Thanks. I just searched the package repo and added the necessary style rules.

Comment: Thank GOD, it helped you, 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added contrast text and default background color in the palette json.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: '#1D2951',
            contrastText: '#fff',
        },
        secondary: {
            main: '#28D9C3',
            contrastText: '#fff',
        },
        background: {
            default: '#fff'
        }
    },
```

Though this may not be relevant at the next release as they are moving the library in the `material-ui/core` library.

Answer (score 1):

Try using material UI's internal color palette, like so

```js
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import purple from '@material-ui/core/colors/purple';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: purple[500],
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Using material color palette resolved the bug. Thanks. But how do I convert a random hex code into the material color palette? I need to re-produce the exact hex code mentioned in the question.

Comment: I believe the error was coming from setting the contrastText property as 'white', instead of a hex value. either way you should write all color values in hex code... It should work.

Comment: The error is still there when I remove `contrastText` property from the code snippet I shared. I just needed to override the styles which threw the error from the library.

Comment:  Could you give more info on your setup, when the error comes on and what you've tried??